# Formulário Delphi MDIChild pisca ao abrir em modo modal

Tags: delphi, mdi

Possuo um formulário `MDIChild` que abro da seguinte maneira:

```
Application.CreateForm(TfrmManProduto, frmManProduto);
```

Porém, algumas vezes preciso desse formulário em modal... 
com alguma dicas adaptei meu código da seguinte maneira para 
abrir ele em modo modal:

```
Application.CreateForm(TfrmManProduto, frmManProduto);  
frmManProduto.FormStyle   := fsNormal;                 
frmManProduto.Visible     := False;
frmManProduto.Position    := poMainFormCenter;
frmManProduto.ShowModal;
```

Dessa maneira funciona, mas ele pisca até mostrar na tela.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de não piscar/mostrar o formulário
até chegar na chamada `frmManProduto.ShowModal`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina a propriedade `Visible` e `FormStyle` do formulário como `False` e `fsNormal` respectivamente por padrão e crie um método construtor que recebe um parâmetro informando se o formulário será `modal` ou não, mais ou menos assim:

```
type
  TfrmManProduto = class(TForm)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; isModal: Boolean); reintroduce;
  end;

implemetation

TfrmManProduto.Create(AOwner: TComponent; isModal: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Position := poMainFormCenter;

  if not (isModal) then
  begin
    FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
    Visible := True;
  end;
end;
```

Para criar o formulário seria assim:

```
frmManProduto := TfrmManProduto.Create(Application, True);
frmManProduto.ShowModal();
```

Comment: bom dia Roberto, fiz conforme passou, porem, nas linhas `frmManProduto.FormStyle   := fsNormal;` e `Visible := True`; gera exception... tentei adicionar `inherited Create(AOwner);` dentro do contrutor mas não resolveu.. acho q estou deixando passar algo..

Comment: o `frmManProduto` ainda é NIL nesses situações, por isso não aceita alterações..

Comment: Alterei, agora deve funcionar, montei o código meio que correndo e não percebi que estava referenciando a variável, também tinha esquecido do `inherited Create`. Mas esta corrigido na resposta

Comment: funcionou, mas, na forma modal ele cria, mostra na tela mas nao fica modal... tentei colocar um showmodal  apos a criacao mas apresenta erro, tentei colocar apos setar `position`, nesse caso ele abre modal, mas, ao fechar ele chama os ONSHOW E ONCREATE do form... achei mto estranho e nao consegui descobrir o motivo...

Comment: O `ShowModal` tem que ser após o `Create` e não durante, alterei a resposta, coloquei o `ShowModal` para exemplo.

Comment: testei dessa maneira, e recebo a mensagem 'Cannot make a visible window modal', na chamada `frmManProduto := TfrmManProduto.Create(Application, True);` ele ja cria o formulario e mostra na tela, se eu adicionar `frmManProduto.ShowModal();` ele me retorna a mensagem acima...

Comment: @FelipeSachetti alterei a resposta, agora consegui testar na minha máquina e funcionou.

Comment: perfeito... mto obrigado roberto, resolver meu problema...